# Trouble writing list of data in an excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, openpyxl

I've written a script in python to get some information from a webpage and write them accordingly to an excel file. Upon execution, the data are getting parsed in the right way. However, the problem is I can write them to an excel file using `openpyxl` library. If the data is a single item and supposed to fit in a single cell, I could have managed that. The data here is a list which I would like to write across columns.

This is how the data look like:

```
['BBC FRONTLINE LIMITED 17 Apr 1990 - 10 Dec 1993', 'FRONTLINE (EMAP 11 Oct 1988 - 17 Apr 1990', 'EMAP FRONTLINE LIMITED 20 Feb 1987 - 11 Oct 1988', 'N.J. PUBLISHING CO. LIMITED(THE) 08 Jul 1937 - 20 Feb 1987']
```

I would like to seperate them from the `commas` and write across columns in the first row.

More like (in `row 1`):

```
col1    col2    col3      col4  and so on
part1   part2   part3     part4
```

This is the script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('container.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

link = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00329613"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
items = soup.select_one("#content-container")
previnfo = [' '.join([item.select_one("td[id^='previous-name-']").get_text(strip=True),' '.join(item.select_one("td[id^='previous-date-']").get_text(strip=True).split())]) for item in items.select("#previousNameTable tr")[1:]]

ws.append(previnfo)
wb.save("container.xlsx")
print(previnfo)
```

Btw, I've already a workbook named `container.xlsx`, which I'm loading to write the content.

Comment: Would CSV file type be of interest?

Comment: Thanks @Nivii1406 for your comment. I know how to write this in a csv file. I'm only interested in writing them in an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below approach to get the required output across columns.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('container.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']

link = "https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/00329613"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
items = soup.select_one("#content-container")
previnfo = [' '.join([item.select_one("td[id^='previous-name-']").get_text(strip=True),' '.join(item.select_one("td[id^='previous-date-']").get_text(strip=True).split())]) for item in items.select("#previousNameTable tr")[1:]]

for I in range(0,len(previnfo)):
    ws.cell(row=1,column=1+I).value = previnfo[I]
wb.save("container.xlsx")
```